# UnicodeError enviando un correo en django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, email, unicode

Estoy obteniendo este error cada vez que trato de enviar un correo:

```
UnicodeError at /accounts/email/

encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
class SendEmailView(generic.FormView):
    form_class = forms.EmailForm
    template_name = 'accounts/email.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:email')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.send_email()
        return super(SendEmailView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Archivo `forms.py`:

```
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField()
    message = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()

    def send_email(self):
        send_mail(
            self.cleaned_data['subject'],
            self.cleaned_data['message'],
            self.cleaned_data['email'],
            [self.cleaned_data['email']],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
        print(self.cleaned_data['email'])
```

Archivo `settings.py`:

```
# email settings
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
```

Archivo `urls.py`:

```
path('email/', views.SendEmailView.as_view(), name='email'),
```

Archivo `email.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Estoy usando un servidor de prueba como lo indica la [documentacion de django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#configuring-email-for-development)

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```